# Как реализовать функцию для транскодирования данных, содержащих битовые поля?

Tags: python

Реализовать функцию для транскодирования данных, содержащих битовые поля. В решении необходимо использовать побитовые операции. Неиспользуемые поля результата должны содержать нулевые биты.

Подскажите пожалуйста как читать эти шкалы внизу, и как это отражается на конечных числах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тесты:

```
main(11801737)
'0x900168'

main(7488988)
'0xc00ae4'

main(10776582)
'0x600148'

main(12913782)
'0x600f8a'
```

Comment: Отличное задание, попробуйте сделать сами. Как будут конкретные вопросы - обращайтесь (сначала к поиску, а потом задавайте тут.

Comment: Как читать: шкалы по 24 бита, нумерация справа налево от 0 до 23. Пространство между каждыми соседними засечками - один бит. Что должно получиться - ну вот например группу из четырех битов T1 нужно перенести из правого крайнего положения в крайнее левое. Аналогично остальные. Серая часть судя по условию просто пустой должна остаться.